# Posts per minute, time of day graphs

Tags: feature-request, site-activity

This would be pretty cool to have, a type of manifestation of current site activity, unobtrusively integrated into a site color or graphic.  Kind of `posts per minute` bar, indicating activity level of the site.

Low activity:

[image: low activity]

medium activity

[image: medium]

high activity

[image: high activity]

very high activity

[image: very high activity]

The purpose of this bar is to "show off" how active the stackexchange site is at the moment.

Comment: I think this would be a bit redundant. There is always high activity on StackOverflow. I can't see the analytics, but I'm willing to be they're always really high.

Comment: This seems utterly pointless. What are we supposed to *do* about it if/when the site activity level changes?